# Disable drag Phaser Box2D

Tags: box2d, drag, phaser-framework

How can I disable drag Phaser Box2D?

I have:

```
this.game.input.onDown.add(this.mouseDragStart, this);
this.game.input.addMoveCallback(this.mouseDragMove, this);
this.game.input.onUp.add(this.mouseDragEnd, this);
```

But, I need disable this for a element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of these does the trick. This is only good, if you intend to switch the input back on later. Otherwise try to not enable drag/input in the first place.

```
sprite.input.enabled = false;

sprite.input.draggable = false;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks, but this does not work for me, but I found a temporal solution and was:
Validate if the event 'click down' is different from the position and the space by object occupied that I want to disable.